# meteor - How to add a subdocument as reference with SimpleSchema

Tags: meteor, simple-schema

I have the following SimpleSchema

```
Schema.Team = new SimpleSchema({
    name:{
        type:String
    },
    members: {
        type: [Schema.User],
        optional:true
    }
});
```

I would like to insert (on the server) a new team document with the current user, as a reference (not as an embedded document).

I have tried:

```
Teams.insert({name:"theName",members:[Meteor.user()]}) // works but insert the user as an embedded doc.

Teams.insert({name:"theName",members:[Meteor.user()._id]}) // Error: 0 must be an object
```

I have also tried in two steps:

```
var id = Teams.insert({name:teamName});
Teams.update({ _id: id },{ $push: { 'users': Meteor.user()._id } });
```

Then I have another error I don't understand: `Error: When the modifier option is true, validation object must have at least one operator`

So how can I insert a document with a reference to another schema?

Comment: If you're storing the _id to each user instead of the object you need to adjust your schema to be of `type: [String]`

Comment: When autoform is saving such a doc the id is as string but the schema is still User.Schema

Comment: Which is why it fails to update.  It's trying to save a String where the schema expects an object.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to store an array of `userId`s in your `Team` collection try:

```
Schema.Team = new SimpleSchema({
    name:{
        type:String
    },
    members: {
        type: [String],
        optional:true
    }
});
```

Then

```
Teams.insert({ name: "theName", members: [Meteor.userId()] });
```

Should work. Later when you want to add an additional id you can just:

```
Teams.update({ _id: teamId },{ $addToSet: { members: Meteor.userId() }});
```

Comment: like $addToSet better as it only add a value if it's not already present. Seems more appropriate in this case where Team members should be a set of unique userIds

Comment: Thanks, I understand, but something still puzzles me: If I do the same with Autoform (let's say with a quickform in a template with a text input in which I paste the id) it works.

Answer (score 0):

The following is probably the syntax you are after, assuming you are also using `AutoForm`.

If you are using `collection2`, you can also add an autovalue for when a team is created to automatically add the creator to that team for more convenience.

```
Schema.Team = new SimpleSchema({
  name: {
    type:String
  },
  members: {
    type: [String],
    defaultValue: [],
    allowedValues: function () {
      // only allow references to the user collection.
      return Meteor.users.find().map(function (doc) {
        return doc._id
      });
    },
    autoform: {
      // if using autoform, this will display their username as the option instead of their id.
      options: function () {
        return Meteor.users.find().map(function (doc) {
          return {
            value: doc._id,
            label: doc.username // or something
          }
        })
      }
    },
    autoValue: function () {
      if (this.isInsert && !this.isFromTrustedCode) {
        return [this.userId];
      }
    }
  }
});
```